# Terminate current SSIS package in C# Script Task without exception/error

Tags: c#, ssis

I'm trying to stop the package execution from within a Script Task. According to [MSDN Article: RunningPackage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.runningpackage.stop.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) just `RunningPackage.Stop();` should work but I get the error *"An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.RunningPackage.Stop()"* this way:

```
    public void Main() 
    {
        RunningPackage.Stop(); // Object reference error.
    }
```

So i tried the following:

```
    public void Main() 
    {
        RunningPackage package = new RunningPackage();
        package.Stop();       
    }
```

This way I doesn't get the underlined code as an error, but when saving the edited script SSIS says *"Scripts contained in the package have compilation errors"*. `using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;` was imported.

What's the problem? Is there any other way to stop the current package totally in C# without getting errors?

Comment: You're trying to halt the currently running package or some other package from within a script task?

Comment: I'm trying to halt the currently running package from within the script task.

Comment: The linked MSDN code is for an external caller to signal that a currently running package should wrap it up. Let me see what options could be available

Comment: How would you know when the package should stop running? In my mind, I see a control flow, N tasks associated, some in parallel, some in serial. *X* happens and now we need to stop, somewhat gracefully. It could be that you set an Expression on **EVERY** executables' `Disabled` tied to a package level boolean variable called `PleaseStop` The default value for that is False but when *X* happens, that gets turned to True which then makes everything Disabled. That won't stop things in flight but it would stop anything new from starting. An approach like that work for you?

Comment: Yes I tried it and it solved my problem. Great idea. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my mind, I see a control flow, *N* tasks associated, some in parallel, some in serial. **X** event happens and now we need to stop, somewhat gracefully.

It could be that you set an Expression on EVERY executables' `Disabled` property tied to a package level boolean variable called `PleaseStop`. The default value for that is False but when X happens, that gets turned to True which then makes everything Disabled.

That won't stop things in flight but it would stop anything new from starting.